# PHP Can you update a var inside a string?

Tags: php, variables

If you have

```
$a = 'World'

$str = 'Hello '.$a

$a = ' John Doe'
```

Is there a way in PHP that `$str` would now receive the changed value from `$a`?
What I know I get: `$str = 'Hello World'`, what I would like: `$str = 'Hello John Doe'`

I know this could be done by replacing the old value with str_replace, but I would like to ask if there is a way that this var could be passed by reference or something.

Comment: You can't change the previous value after it's been used like that. To what purpose do you need this? Sounds a little like an XY-problem to me.

Comment: Not as easily as you make it sound, I think. The string is "done" and fixed at line 2. Any changes has to be done on the new string.

Comment: @Qirel I am sorry if I asked something stupid. I simply thought since php provides prepared statements for SQL something similar could be achieved for simple strings.

Comment: Maybe you can use an array to hold the string parts? This will at least (maybe) make it easier to change the values later.

Comment: A prepared statement is a bit different, because it uses placeholders, and the logic behind it is a little more complex. Once you print the string with `Hello World`, you *can* replace it by using `str_replace()`, but that's not the same really.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short once you've set a string, its set. It doesn't get bound with arguments on anything like that.

People tend to use formatted strings for things like this:

```
 $formattedString = "Hello %s".PHP_EOL;
 $possibleValues = [ "World", "John Doe" ];

 foreach ($possibleValues as $value) {
      printf($formattedString, $value);
 }
```

Prints:

> Hello World
>
> Hello John Doe

See it run at : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a9e8e7c71058b1e9a9212fbb398f9c40d20881b5

Comment: Thank you! ... I have to wait 8 minutes to accept this :D

Comment: @CMA as a sidenote if you don't need to print the string but only to store it as a variable you can use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference at variable $a

```
$a = 'World';
$ra = &$a;
$str = 'Hello '.$ra;
$a = ' John Doe';
```

Comment: If you `echo $str` you still get "Hello World" as the output.